# automatic set reply-to header in osx mail

Tags: macos, email, imap

I use a google account, say myaccount@google.com for work and I use aliases for the various projects I'm working on. Thus, for project1, I use myaccount+projet1@google.com, for project2 myaccount+projet2@google.com and so on. I do not need to add additional account in Mail since GMail ignores what's after the "+" sign.
Now, in the configuration of my mail account, I put all the addresses (including the ones with aliases) in the "Email address" field, separated by commas. So I can send a message from any of my emails myaccount+project*@google.com.

My question is about the "reply-to" header that I have to manually choose in order to receive the mail in the right folder. I looked in the settings and could not find a solution. Do you know any way to do it automatically (set the reply-to header the same as the from)? Apple script perhaps?
I know that I can use the "default write" command but that only allows to specify one specific "reply-to" header to all the emails, which is not what I'm looking for.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: +1 I wish to know the answer as well, or the name of another piece of software that will do this.  It seems simple to me:  If a message arrives with the header  To: myaccount+xyz@gmail, then I'd like to set Reply-To: myaccount+xyz@gmail.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my WIP,  I'm posting it now incase I never finish it.  Hopefully I'll update this with an example that reads the required fields, rather than being hardcoded.

(3rd and probably final update)

Apologies if this doesn't do exactly what you need, but it did exactly what I needed, and I believe you requirements are simpler than mine.

```
-- Reply to current message with additional header changes.
-- (To be triggered from Keyboard Maestro, or ControllerMate on Alt-R)

-- function to read/focus/change data in message field
-- usage: set fieldValue to message_field("reply_to", false) 
--        message_field("reply to", "moron")
on message_field(fieldname, newValue)
    local tElements, tElement, tField, tValue, tClass
    tell application "System Events"
        tell process "Mail"
            set frontmost to true
            set tElements to scroll areas of window 1
            repeat with tElement in tElements
                set tName to get name of tElement as string
                try
                    set tField to text field 1 of tElement
                    ignoring white space and punctuation

                        if (name of tField as string = fieldname) then
                            try
                                set tValue to get value of tField as string
                            on error
                                set tValue to ""
                            end try

                            set focused of tField to true

                            if (newValue ≠ false) then
                                set value of tField to newValue -- as string

                            end if
                            exit repeat
                        end if
                    end ignoring
                end try
            end repeat
        end tell
    end tell
    return tValue
end message_field

-- split function (julifos @ macscripter.net)
to split(someText, delimiter)
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to delimiter
    set someText to someText's text items
    set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {""} --> restore delimiters to default value
    return someText
end split

-- Get information from current/selected message
tell application "Mail"
    set theSignatureName to "Signature #1"
    set theMessages to the selected messages of the front message viewer
    set theMessage to first item of theMessages

    -- Get the email address (ours, hopefully) the message was sent to
    set theMessageWasTo to address of first to recipient of theMessage as string


    -- Unfortunately, it seesm that Mail doesn't honour the existing Reply-To header
    -- when a reply is triggered from a script, instead of from the Reply menu.
    -- So here is a bit of a dance to get it.
    set theMessageHeaders to headers of theMessage
    try
        set theMessageReplyToWas to first item of {reply to} of theMessage -- (thx to Brian Christmas)
        tell me to set theMessageReplyToWas to item 1 of split(theMessageReplyToWas, ",")
    on error
        set theMessageReplyToWas to sender of theMessage
    end try

    -- you can also use: set temp to {deleted status, all headers, was replied to, flag index, date received, message id, background color, subject, read status, flagged status, message size, date sent, junk mail status, source, sender, was forwarded, was redirected, content} of foo 



    -- set Theheaders to all headers of theMessage -- If you want to get all the headers in text form and process manually
    -- set mySource to source of theMessage -- If you want the message source

    set theOutgoingMessage to reply theMessage with opening window

    -- I want to set "Reply-To" to be the address the message was sent to
    tell me to message_field("reply to", theMessageWasTo)

    tell theOutgoingMessage
        -- I don't like this, as it adds an extra recipient
        make new to recipient with properties {address:theMessageWasTo}
        -- so I'll do it my way
        tell me to message_field("to", theMessageWasTo)
    end tell

    -- It's easier if you just want to change the sender or signature or something
    -- set message signature of theOutgoingMessage to signature theSignatureName
    -- set sender of theOutgoingMessage to "Federico Viticci "

end tell

-- Now all that remains is to set the focus back to the body of the message.
```

Comment: +1 just because the OP is too ignorant to upvote you himself.

Comment: @trojanfoe very kind, i'm just waiting for an applescript expert to come and reduce it all to 10 lines of code.  i'd also like to automaticaly add aliases to the mail account.  but hey.